# podspec prepare_command modify local library pod Support Files xxx-prefix.pch

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

This is script
`#!/usr/bin/env ruby
prefix_pch_path = "ExampleMac/Pods/Target Support Files/xxx/xxx-prefix.pch"

prefix_header_contents = File.read(prefix_pch_path)
puts prefix_header_contents

prefix_header_contents.gsub!(/#include "pygl.h".*\n/, "")

new_prefix_header_contents = "#include "pygl.h"\n#{prefix_header_contents}"

File.write(prefix_pch_path, new_prefix_header_contents)

puts new_prefix_header_contents
`

This is prepare_command, The script file and podspec are in the same directory.
`s.prepare_command = <<-CMD ruby update_prefix_header.rb CMD`

The above script successfully modifies the xxx-prefix.pch file when executed in the command line.
Without a doubt, the prefix_pch_path path is fine

However, when executing pod install through the prepare_command in the podspec, the xxx-prefix.pch file is not being modified.